# useEffect of react hooks throwing an error when used inside axios

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**How can I fix the following issue?:**

I am using react hooks to for primereact datatable. And when I am trying to use `useEffect` inside an axios call(commented out portion of the code in the code below) similar to the [sandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-elbakyan-ui8ev?file=/src/CarsTable.js:16-26), I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

It's most likely because of #2 above. Should I try calling the api inside useEffect instead of using axios here?

However, when I use the `useEffect` outside the axios, the way it is, it works fine, but I want it to be inside axios so that I can use the response to display the data.

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import { Dropdown } from 'primereact/dropdown';
import { DataTable } from 'primereact/datatable';
import {Column} from "primereact/column";
import testdata from "./test-data.json";


const RequestForm = (props) => {
    
    console.log(props.companyRequest.requestId);
    let editedcompanyRequestId = props.companyRequest.requestId;

   
    // START: Datatable related code with React Hooks

    const init = (initialState) => initialState;

    const reducer = (state, action) => {
            switch (action.type) {
                case "dataLoaded":
                return { ...state, results: action.payload, loading: false };
                default:
                throw new Error();
            }
    };

    const initialState = {
        results: [],
        loading: true
      };
      const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState, init);
      const { results, loading } = state;

      var receivedResponse;
      axios
         .get("api/companyLookup?requestId="+editedcompanyRequestId)
         .then(response => {
              console.log('Printing Response.data ....')
              console.log(response.data);
              receivedResponse = response.data;
              console.log("Received Response below inside axios")
              console.log(receivedResponse);
            //   useEffect(() => {
            //     if (loading) {
            //       dispatch({
            //         type: "dataLoaded",
            //         payload: receivedResponse.map((row) => {
            //           const [vin, year, brand, color] = row.split(",");
            //           return {
            //             vin,
            //             year,
            //             brand,
            //             color
            //           };
            //         }, [])
            //       });
            //     }
            //   }, [loading]);
        
         }).catch(err => console.log(err));  

         console.log("Received Response below");
         console.log(receivedResponse);

      useEffect(() => {
        if (loading) {
          dispatch({
            type: "dataLoaded",
            payload: testdata.map((row) => {
              const [vin, year, brand, color] = row.split(",");
              return {
                vin,
                year,
                brand,
                color
              };
            }, [])
          });
        }
      }, [loading]);


     // END: Datatable related code with React Hooks


    
    
    



    return (
        <div>
            
            <div id="formDiv">
                <Growl ref={growl}/>
                <Form className="form-column-3">
                    <div className="form-field field-full-width">
                        <DataTable value={results}>
                           <Column field="vin" header="Company ID" />
                           <Column field="year" header="Company File Name" />
                           <Column field="brand" header="Company Description" />
                           <Column field="color" header="Owner ID" />
                        </DataTable>
                    </div>  
                  
                    <div className="btn-group-right">
                        <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary"
                                type="submit">Submit</Button>
                        <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleReset}
                                style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="button">Reset</Button>
                        <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={props.onCancel}
                                style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="button">Cancel</Button>
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

};


export const CompanyRequestEnhancedFormEdw = withFormik({


     mapPropsToValues: props => {

        // console.log("Props TESTING Inside const companyRequestEnhancedFormEdw = withFormik({ ****************************************************************");
        // console.log(props);
    

        return {
           

            //some code here
        }
    },

    validationSchema:validationSchema,
    handleSubmit(values, {props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}) {
       //some code
    },
    setFieldValue(field, value, shouldVal) {
        console.log('In setFieldValue')
    },

    displayName: 'Company Request Form',
})(RequestForm)
```

Comment: `Should I try calling the api inside useEffect instead of using axios here?`: Yes

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch data, do it inside the `useEffect()` hook.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  axios
    .get("url")
    .then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, []);
```

When your data is fetched, the state value is updated causing the page to re-render.

Example [Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-goldstine-hqhct?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks. Can you modify the useEffect based on my sandbox example? https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-elbakyan-ui8ev?file=/src/CarsTable.js:16-26  It's using useReducer and if(loading) inside useEffect which is confusing me while using axios inside my code

Comment: I will take a look and see what I can do